# Ti.UI.Labels Overlap while using label.left=previous_lablel.right in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm new bee to Titanium,

I want to set the UILabel.left based on the previous UILabel.right and I'm using **index.js** to execute this functionality

Here is the code:

```js
$.password_label.right=$.login_button.center;// This works fine
$.register_label.left=$.password_label.right;// Issue in this line
$.index.open();
```

Image in which it overlaps, though my aim is to make it side by side.[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in Titanium framework, Button.center is a point (Object : {x,y}) ...

you should use layout : horizontal to achieve this :

```
//In your xml file :
<View class='labeslcontainer'>
  <Label id="labelPassword"/>
  <Label id="labelRegister"/>
</View>
```

and the in your tss file :

```
".labeslcontainer":{
   layout:horizontal
 }
"#labelPassword":{
   text:'your text |',
}
"#labelRegister":{
   text: 'your text',
   left : 7
}
```

and so on. Using left in horizontal container will position your labels side by side.

Comment: Actually I'm iOS Xcode Expert. Great that you helped me with the solution. "horizontal" and Can I know how can I put the horizontal layout to center of the view but it must center to x but not y, I mean it should be below login button

Comment: make textFields & login button & labeslcontainer view  in a vertical container( a view with `layout : 'vertical'`)  then use top property of button & other textFields :)